# Python limiting digits as an int in a input

Tags: python, int, limiting

So as the title suggests I am trying to limit integers in a input to 11, has anyone got a simple solution to this?

Edit. Sorry should be a little more precise, I'm not trying to limit the actual input to 11. I'm trying to limit the amount of digits inputted to 11 such as,

input 123 = okay
input 123456789123 = invaid

Comment: What do you mean with "to 11" ?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please share what you tried, your code etc...
Also try to be more precise : what does "in a input to 11" mean to you ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
while True:
    a = input ("Input: ")
    if len(a) < 11: #excepted as string
        a = int(a)          
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(x):
  if x >= 1E+11:
     raise SomeError

  "Do something"
```

Something like this u mean?

Comment: Should be `x > 1E+11 - 1` or `x >= 1E+11`, no? `1E+11` has 12 digits

Comment: Correct!,  x >= 1E+11

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to only accept integers in the range `0 <= x <= 11`, you could use:

```
while True:
    try:
        inpt = int(input('Enter number less than 12: '))
        if inpt in range(12):
            break
    except:
       pass 
    print('Invalid input.')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only accept a maximum of 11-digit numbers, just compare it to a twelve digit number:

```
def up_to_digits(n):
    while True:
       try:
           r = int(input('Enter number: '))
           if r >= 10 ** n or r <= -(10 ** n):
               print('Maximum {} digits'.format(n))
               raise ValueError
           return r 
       except ValueError:
           pass
```